# How to make a download link button for doc files in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a form to edit, upload and download doc files. The form is like this-

[image: form]

The edit form has many input fields. But I am showing only the file fields.

**My questions:**

1. How to download available files ? I was given a base url. The base url is - "http://45..........". And my codes are-

   Brd Doc

   ```
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy1"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach1"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>

        <label for="">Sow Doc</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy2"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach2"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
        <label for="">Srs Doc</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy3"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach3"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
        <label for="">Uat Doc</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy4"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach4"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
        <label for="">Technical Soln</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy5"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach5"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
        <label for="">Finan break</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy6"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach6"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
        <label for="">Final finan</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref="softCopy7"
          v-on:change="softCopyAttach7"
        /><a href="">Download</a><br /><br>
      </div>
   ```

I have included anchor link to get files from backend. So what to write inside  to download the file?

Here is a pic of the datas that I am getting from backend using api-
[image: data pic]

The file keys are- **brd_doc**, **sow_doc** and so on.....

My second question is suppose I have inserted a file during create new in key **brd_doc**. After insertion, when I will edit, I have inserted another file in key **sow_doc** and kept **brd_doc** empty. Now the file which I had uploaded during create new in key **brd_doc** gets deleted. But I want to keep it. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can download the file using absolute url of the uploaded file (baseUrl + filepath).

Comment: For your second question, on server side check if file was uploaded only after overwrite the database column.

Comment: Understood the first one. But didnt understand the second. Tell me please.

Comment: Sure let me explain, when you uploading the files all file will have different name/key, on server side, you can check the file uploaded or not (using file name, in php you will get files in $_FILES). If user uploaded the particular file then only update that column in db.

Comment: I am confused. Dont know what to do

Comment: Can you show the backend insert/ update code?

Comment: Backend is done in node.js. You need Node.js code ?